Firebase connection error, call firebase.initializeApp() error in but i already initialized it
screenshot of error
I was trying to setup firebase auth and done all the steps but i am new to it and other yt tutorials covers something from previous versions and there are some changes inside build gradle app and project level, i think i'd done pretty much everything but there is an error of initializing app. Please guide me what could be the problem and what could i do in this point?
my main.dart
import 'package:ecom/signup.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'provider/cart_provider.dart';
import 'provider/favourite_provider.dart';

// void main() async {
//   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
//   await Firebase.initializeApp();
//   runApp(const MyApp());
// }

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  try {
    print("Firebase initialized successfully");
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Failed to initialize Firebase: $e");
  }
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => CartProvider()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => FavoriteProvider()),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
            useMaterial3: true,
          ),
          home: const sign_up(),
        ),
      );
}

my gradle files
project lvl



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app lvl
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.ecom"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
       
        applicationId = "com.example.ecom"
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies{
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.1.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.10" apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false
}

include ":app"





Try to downgrade kotlin version on settings.grdle file with plugins as...
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.20" apply false. Run flutter clean and clean gradle with goinng to android folder -> ./gradlew clean

did u try to add options to your firebase object
Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

in case this not work try to follow Firebase Doc the CLI prevent things like that

That worked thanks

great can u please mark my answer as the correct one @MTashkeelPasha that will help me a lot

This error may be in Firebase configuration. Try Firebase CLI to configure Firebase in your project. It's very simple and the best way to configure Firebase.
